# Update Core Data when new version comes

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, app-store

I have an app which uses core data and on app store.

How do I update the Core Data entities on the launch of the new app version?

Answer (score 0):

You should go through `Coredata Migration` tutorials.

Ref: https://www.raywenderlich.com/114084/core-data-migrations-tutorial-lightweight-migrations

> with Core Data, you can migrate toward the future with every new
>   release of your app. The migration process will update data created
>   with a previous version of the data model to match the current data
>   model.